# Plotting the derivative of the solution of Solve

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have an implicit function, and I'm trying to plot the derivative of the solution of this function.

The function is:

```
p = \[Phi]/(1/\[Beta]) + ((1 - \[Phi]) \[Phi] (1 - \[Lambda]) \
\[Beta])/(((W - A) 1/\[Beta] + \[Phi] A/
      p) 1/\[Beta] + \[Phi]*(1 - \[Phi]) A/p)/(
 1/\[Beta] (\[Lambda]/((W - A) 1/\[Beta] + \[Phi] (A/
      p)  ) + (1 - \[Lambda])/(((W - A) 1/\[Beta] + \[Phi] A/
         p) 1/\[Beta] + \[Phi] (1 - \[Phi]) A/p)))
```

And I would like to plot the derivative of the following expression w.r.t `\[Phi]`

```
\[Phi]/p ((1-\[Phi]) A + 1/\[Beta] A )
```

I've been trying to first solve for `p` explicitly, and plug the solution into the expression above and plot the derivative of the expression, but kept getting an error. My code is :

```
Manipulate[
 ans = p /. 
   Solve[p - \[Phi]/(
      1/\[Beta]) - ((1 - \[Phi]) \[Phi] (1 - \[Lambda]) \[Beta])/(((W \
- A) 1/\[Beta] + \[Phi] A/p) 1/\[Beta] + \[Phi]*(1 - \[Phi]) A/p)/(
      1/\[Beta] (\[Lambda]/((W - A) 1/\[Beta] + \[Phi] (A/
           p)  ) + (1 - \[Lambda])/(((W - A) 1/\[Beta] + \[Phi] A/
              p) 1/\[Beta] + \[Phi] (1 - \[Phi]) A/p))) == 0, p],
 Plot[Evaluate[
   D[f[\[Phi]] == \[Phi]/
      ans[[2]] ((1 - \[Phi]) A + 1/\[Beta] A), \[Phi]]], {\[Phi], 
   0.01, 1}], {A, 10, 500}, {\[Beta], 0.001, 1}, {W, 100, 
  10^9}, {\[Lambda], 0.01, 1}]
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
"Manipulate:Manipulate argument \
Plot[Evaluate[\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Phi]\)]\((f[\
\[Phi]] == \((\[Phi]\\\ Power[<<2>>])\)\\\ \((Times[<<2>>] + 
     Times[<<2>>])\))\)\)],{\[Phi],0.01,1}] does not have the correct \
form for a variable specification"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Manipulate[
 Module[{ans, f,
   β = Rationalize[ββ, 0],
   λ = Rationalize[λλ, 0]},
  ans = Solve[
    p == ϕ/(1/β) + ((1 - ϕ) ϕ (1 - λ) \
β)/(((W - A) 1/β + ϕ A/
               p) 1/β + ϕ*(1 - ϕ) A/
            p)/(1/β (λ/((W - A) 1/β + ϕ (A/
                 p)) + (1 - λ)/(((W - A) 1/β + ϕ A/
                   p) 1/β + ϕ (1 - ϕ) A/p))), p]; 
  f = D[ϕ/p ((1 - ϕ) A + 1/β A) /. ans, ϕ] // 
    Simplify;
  Plot[Evaluate@f, {ϕ, 0.01, 1},
   PlotLegends -> Automatic]],
 {{A, 10}, 10, 500, 1,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{ββ, 0.001, "β"}, 0.001, 1, 0.001,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{W, 100}, Outer[Times, {1, 2, 5, 7, 10},
     10^Range[2, 8]] // Flatten // Union},
 {{λλ, 0.01, "λ"}, 0.01, 1, 0.002,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]